# Is company-sponsored training considered compensation?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, compensation

I have a company looking to hire me to help setup their new flight department. During that process and while I am on salary they want to pay for me to get the rest of my ratings. I don't believe this crosses any lines, but wanted your thoughts.

I am in the US so I’m concerned with the FAA. I’m particularly concerned with the FAA and IRS having issues with someone else paying for my flight training. I am concerned they may see it as some form of compensation for someone who doesn’t have a commercial license.